# different behavior for group_by for data.table vs. data.frame

Tags: r, data.table, dplyr

When dplyr::mutate is used on a grouped data.table, the grouping is subsequently lost. This behavior does not occur for data.frame. Is this a bug?  I am using dplyr_0.4.1           and data.table_1.9.4.

```
require(data.table)
require(dplyr)

by_cyl_df <- group_by( mtcars, cyl ) %>%
    dplyr::mutate( . , 
        maxmpg = max( mpg )
    )
groups( by_cyl_df )
```

> [[1]] cyl

```
by_cyl_dt   <- group_by( as.data.table(mtcars), cyl ) %>%
    dplyr::mutate( . , 
        maxmpg = max( mpg )
    )
groups( by_cyl_dt )
```

> NULL

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is an [open dplyr issue](https://github.com/hadley/dplyr/issues/919). After a `mutate`, the groups are dropped. If you look at the classes you can see this happening.

```
by_cyl_dt_gg   <- group_by( as.data.table(mtcars), cyl )

class(by_cyl_dt_gg)
# [1] "grouped_dt" "tbl_dt"     "tbl"        "data.table" "data.frame"
class(by_cyl_dt_gg %>% mutate(max=max(mpg)))
# [1] "tbl_dt"     "tbl"        "data.table" "data.frame"
```

And since it's no longer grouped (the `groups_dt` class is dropped), the `groups` function returns NULL for this type of object

```
> dplyr:::groups.tbl_dt
function (x) 
{
    NULL
}
<environment: namespace:dplyr>
```